# Return class specifying generic type from dart factory constructor

Tags: dart, generics

I have a generic class and two subclasses, one of which specifies the generic parameter. I want to have two factory constructors in my superclass returning the subclasses, but that doesn't work. A static method would do the trick, but am I doing something wrong? If that's just not supported, is there a reason for that?

```dart
class A<T> {
  final T generic;
  final int known;
 
  A._internal(this.generic, this.known);
  
  factory A.b1(int known) => B(known); // doesn't work
  factory A.c1(T first, int known) => C(first, known);
}

class B extends A<void> {
  B(int known): super._internal(null, known);
}

class C<T> extends A<T> {
  C(T generic, int known): super._internal(generic, known);
}
```

Comment: You need to use static methods here since the return type of a factory must be compatible with the class it is part of. Your problem is that by using factory constructor, the following is allowed: `final b1 = A<String>.b1(4);`. But that code cannot be valid based on what the factory constructor `b1` returns. So now `b1` does no longer return a valid object that is compatible with `A<String>`.

Comment: I somehow feel like something like `factory A.b1<void>(int known) => B(known)` should exist to allow this, but I don't know why many things from other languages don't work with dart generics (like defaults or `<T extends Foobar>` or other restrictions on generics) so I'm certainly not the right person to judge.